# push array data in every index of an array using codeigniter php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have two tables `sport_tbl`, `match_tbl`. In sport_tbl, i defined sport_name such as cricket. In match_tbl, I have `match_name`,`match_date`,`sport_id`.

I want to show match_date of every sport_name (ex. i am showing match_date list for cricket sport and i want to show every date has match_name list).

I want to show one distinct `match_date`.

Image
[image]

my controller code:-

```
        $url = 'cricket' // for example first sport_name
    $data['getSportMatch'] = $this->user_model->getSportMatch($url);
```

my model code:-

```
    public function getSportMatch($sport)
{
    $query = $this->db->get_where('match_tbl',array('sport_name' => $sport));
    if($query->num_rows > 0)
    {
        foreach($query->result() as $item){
            $data[] = $item;
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

my code in view:-

```
<div><?php foreach($getSport as $item): ?><h4><?= $item->sport_name; ?></h4><div><?= foreach($getSportMatch as $item): ?>
```

match_date)) ?>here i want to show list match_name of every match_date

My table structure images

1) `sport_tbl`

[image: Sport_tbl]

2) `match_tbl`

[image: match_tbl]

3) another match_tbl

[image]

Comment: can your share two table structure ?

Comment: @VairaMuthu I have added table data image on above please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this coding ...

```
  public function getSportMatch($sport)
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM sport_tbl as st INNER JOIN match_tbl as mt ON  st.sport_id =  mt.sport_id WHERE st.sport_name ='".$sport."'");
    if($query->num_rows > 0)
    {
       $query_result = $query->result_array();

       $final_result = array();

       foreach($query_result as $result ) {

       $date =  $result['match_date'];

       $final_result[$date][] = $result;

       }

       return $final_result;

    }
}
```

View Coding :-

```
 if(isset($final_result)) {

        foreach($final_result as $result) {

        echo $result['match_date']; //  First display match date

  if(isset($result['match_date'])) {
            foreach($result['match_date'] as $match) {

                echo $match['match_name']; // Second listout the match name 

            }
    }
        }

    }
```

Comment: from this code date is repeating. i want distinct date and under this date list of match_name.

Comment: date means match_date field ? and  one sport name also have multiple match table records, that is correct ? otherwise is it not okay, then pls share your query result.

Comment: My Result data

Array ( [0] => Array ( [sport_id] => 2 [sport_name] => Cricket [match_id] => 11 [league_name] => IPL [match_name] => India vd South Africa [match_date] => 2016-01-12 [match_time] => 22:35:00 [bookie_url] => 0 [add_date] => 2016-01-08 09:58:37 [bookie_title] => Bookie ) [1] => Array ( [sport_id] => 2 [sport_name] => Cricket [match_id] => 12 [league_name] => IPL [match_name] => Rajsthan Vs Dehli [match_date] => 2016-01-12 [match_time] => 22:35:00 [bookie_url] => 0 [add_date] => 2016-01-08 12:14:00 [bookie_title] => Bookie )

Comment: I want only unique match_date and every unique match_date has list of match_name on those match_date

Comment: i have added another image of match_tbl above 
3) another match_tbl

Comment: But now how can use this code in view. i mean how can i first i print match_date and print all match_name of this date

Comment: hello @Vaira Muthu any solution please ?

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this in model easily. if i did not understand wrong . you need 2 function in model. 
1. will get sport names
2. will get matches of given sport name

```
//model functions

function get_sports(){
    $data = array();
   $sports = $this->db->select('sport_name')->from('sport_tbl')->get()->result();
      if($sports)
       {
        foreach($sports as $sport){

            $data[$sport->sport_name] = $this->get_matches($sport->sport_name);
        }
        return $data;
       }

}


function get_matches($sport_name){
    $matches =   $this->db->select('*')->from('match_tbl')->where('sport_name',$sport_name)->get()->result();
    return $matches;

}
```

so in view data will be something like this

```
$data => array(
    'cricket'=> array(0 => array(
                                  'match_id' => 11,
                                   'sport_id' = 2 .....

)))
```